# Simple IF Statements in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, uilabel, uitextview

Im using the ZBar Reader SDK

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
// ADD: delegate protocol
< ZBarReaderDelegate >
{
UIImageView *resultImage;
UITextView *resultText;
UILabel *text;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *resultText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *text;
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped;

@end

UITextView *resultText;
IBOutlet UILabel *text;
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize resultImage, resultText, text;

- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
{
// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

// EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];

// present and release the controller
[self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];

}





- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
// ADD: get the decode results
id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
[info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
for(symbol in results)
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    break;

// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the resulting data
resultText.text = symbol.data;


//Below are the IF Statements...
if ((symbol = @"3307210410801")) {
    text.text = @"FarCry 2";
}
else if ((symbol = @"530917119347")) {
    text.text = @"Call of Duty: Black Ops 2";
}
else if ((symbol = @"5021290053694")) {
    text.text = @"Hitman Absolution";
}
else if ((symbol = @"5026555401739")) {
    text.text = @"Red Dead Redemption";
}




// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
resultImage.image =
[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}




- (void) dealloc
{
self.resultImage = nil;
self.resultText = nil;
self.text = nil;


}


- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
return(YES);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

It works so that when resultText shows on my Simulator to be 5021290053694 then 'text' shows "Pingu"

My problem is that Pingu Doesn't disappear when the next number appears, so when 5026555401739 shows then 'text' should show "Shaun of the Dead". Instead it stays as Pingu.

In other words it doesn't deallocate the whichever 'text' was shown first. The first one will stay there until I close the App down and Reopen.

Hopefully this is easy to understand. :)

Thank you in advance.

- Nick

EDIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't compare strings directly like that. It will compare references instead of values. Use `[symbol isEqualToString:@"3307210410801"]` instead

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply Im getting 'No Visible @interface for ZBarSymbol declares the selector "isEqualToString."

I've edited my question to show more of what im working with. 

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You are using `=` which is an assignment operator.

And `==` is a comparison operator.

However to compare two objects you need `isEqualTo:` and it if is string you should do `isEqualToString:`

You code should be :

```
if ([symbol isEqualToString:@"3307210410801"]) {
    text.text = @"LOTR";
}
else if ([symbol isEqualToString: @"530917119347"]) {
    text.text = @"James Bond";
}
else if ([symbol isEqualToString: @"5021290053694"]) {
    text.text = @"Pingu";
}
else if ([symbol isEqualToString: @"5026555401739"]) {
    text.text = @"Shaun of the Dead";
}
```

Comment: Im getting 'No Visible @interface for ZBarSymbol declares the selector "isEqualToString." 

I'm editing the Question to give a better Idea of what my implementation file looks like.

Thanks for the swift reply

Comment: get the text in a string and then use isequaltostring: